# Netbeans Java - Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) on project Sintetizee:

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

Quando eu tento executar meu arquivo Java no Netbeans, este erro aparece

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) on project Sintetizee: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
```

Este é o meu arquivo pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>Sintetizee</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Já tentei dar o comando mvn clean install e aparece "build failure", já reinstalei o Netbeans e nada. A versão do meu Java é o 1.8.0.111

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser o cache do Netbeans. Faz o sequinte, feche o Netbeans e apaque tudo das pastas:

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache

C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\12.0\var
```

(substitua **User** pelo seu usuário e **12.0** pela sua versão do nb)
Agora abra o Netbeans.
Se ele quiser importar algum dado de alguma outra versão dele instalada, diga que não.